# How can I run python code file by taking input names from a txt file instead of writing them in terminal with args parser?

Tags: python

I am running my python file by giving it names of the files required through terminal with specified tags by using args parser. I would like to know if I can link a txt or any file to the code file and just change the input names in the txt file and run the code file without having to add all the inputs to args parser in terminal. The inputs are as follows:

```
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
  parser.add_argument('-m', '--model', required=True,
                      help='File path of .tflite file.')
  parser.add_argument('-i', '--input', required=True,
                      help='File path of image to process.')
  parser.add_argument('-l', '--labels',
                      help='File path of labels file.')
  parser.add_argument('-t', '--threshold', type=float, default=0.4,
                      help='Score threshold for detected objects.')
  parser.add_argument('-o', '--output',
                      help='File path for the result image with annotations')
  args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I used a txt file to keep each filename with its path on different lines and used:

`with open(filename) as f: input_ = f.read().splitlines()`

then use indexes with `input`  to get the filename from each line. For example if I want to get the input from line 1 of the txt file, I would use:

`input1_ = input[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for :

```
python3 file.py < data.txt
```

`file.py` is the code to be run, and `data.txt` contain input data. For example,
**file.py** :

```
a = input("Hello :")
print(a)

b = input()
print(b)
```

**data.txt** :

```
Hello
World
```

running `python3 file.py < data.txt` will give :

```
Hello :Hello
World
```